# how to get all child with specific value from Firebase android kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I want to get just color item in the image from all user in my database. I try this

```
private fun setListPersonOfferService(){
    val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    val userIdReference = database.getReference("user personal data").child("Country")
    val userFilterListener = object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
            // handle error
        }
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            val listTest = dataSnapshot.children.map { it.getValue(HomePageModel::class.java)!! }

                itemAdapter = ItemAdapterHomePage(context ?: return,
                    listTest as ArrayList<HomePageModel>
                )
                itemAdapter?.onItemClick = {
                    Supplier.serviceList[it].state = !Supplier.serviceList[it].state

                    itemAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    Toast.makeText(context, "go to speck", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }

                recyclerView_homePage.apply {
                    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
                    adapter = itemAdapter
                }
            }
        }
    userIdReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(userFilterListener)
}

class HomePageModel(var lastName: String?=null,
                     var town: String?=null,
                     var faculty: String?=null,
                     var languageOfStudy: String?=null )
```

if i change Reference to the specific directory `.child("Turcia").child("Adana").child("Çukurova University").child("Faculty of Business")` it works, but i want to get from all user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to navigate over the `dataSnapshot` in your `onDataChange` to get to the correct child nodes.

To navigate a [`DataSnapshot` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot) you have two main approaches:

1. You already know the key of the child you want to access, in which case you use the [`child()` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#child) to access that specific child node. For example, you could read the marked child in the JSON with `dataSnapshot.child("Turcia/Adana/Çukurova University/Faculty of Business").children.map`, similarly to what you already tried on the reference.
2. You don't know the key of the child nodes, in which case you loop over the [`getChildren()` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#getchildren) of the snapshot. For an example of the latter, see the Firebase documentation on [listening for value events on a list of children](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events).

I think you're looking for the second approach here, but in any case you're dealing with `DataSnapshot`s, there are the ways to get at the data in there.

Comment: `var list = ArrayList<HomePageModel>()
                for (data in dataSnapshot.children){
                    user = data.getValue(HomePageModel::class.java)
                    list.add(user as HomePageModel)
                }` I tried this too but again it didn't work because it only looks at the children in the reference

Comment: That will get you through one level in the JSON. You'll need to make the choice of approaches for each level in your JSON between where you read form, and where your `HomePageModel` class maps to the properties in the JSON.

Comment: can you help me with example Please?

Comment: It's a matter of doing more of the same. Your current `for (data in dataSnapshot.children){` loops over the children of the `Country` node, so `data.key` will be `Turcia`. If you nest an additional loop inside this `for (data2 in data.children){` then you get your `data2.key` will be `Adana`. You need to nest such loops (option 2 from my answer) for each level of the JSON where you don't know the key you want to read. Once you know the key names, you can use option 1 - which is what your `data.getValue(HomePageModel::class.java)` also does.