# How to get children data from 4 layer of parent nodes firebase using android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is how my database looks like, I want to get `date` and `percent` data for each alphabet. Does someone have any idea how to get the data or to create a table that can store date and percent for each alphabet with more than 10 trials?.

[image]

This is what I mean.. I want all data of `A` from each trial.
[image]

Comment: There are two approaches and you'll need a mix of them: 1) if you know the name of the child, you can use `snapshot.child("that name")` to access the specific snapshot, 2) if you don't know the name of the child node, you can loop over `snapshot.getChildren()`. By combining these you can navigate any structure. See my answer here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66409491/how-to-get-all-child-with-specific-value-from-firebase-android-kotlin/66411152#66411152

Comment: the problem is i want to fetch all data from every trial. for example i need data A from every n-trial. do you know how to do it?

Comment: when you fetch data at a location in your database, you also retrieve all of its child nodes

Comment: Hey Nurul. What do you mean by "I need data A from every n-trial"? Please provide a concrete example with the expected result. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo i already edit my post, hope you understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your edited question:

> I want all data of A from each trial.

To get all data that exists beneath A node that corresponds each trail, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Result").child(uid);
uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot trialSnapshot : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : trialSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    if(ds.getKey().equals("A")) {
                        String date = ds.child("Date").getValue(String.class);
                        String percent = ds.child("Percent").getValue(String.class);
                        Log.d(TAG, date + " - " + percent);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

So as you see, you need to loop twice, using "getChildren()". The result in the logcat will be:

```
9/2/12 - 32
2/3/21 - 89
```